# Maven loads wrong dependencies: Jackson codehaus -> fasterxml

Tags: maven

I upgraded a library version from:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.codehaus.jackson</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-mapper-asl</artifactId>
        <version>1.9.13</version>
    </dependency>
```

to

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
        <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.8.9</version>
    </dependency>
```

When running a build or just `mvn dependency:resolve`, it fails with `The following artifacts could not be resolved: org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:2.8.9, org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-mapper-asl:jar:2.8.9: Could not find artifact org.codehaus.jackson:jackson-core-asl:jar:2.8.9 in central ...` on the deployment server. It somehow works when run on my development machine. Both machines (still) using Java7.

Somehow it tries to load the old artifact with the new ID. But there is no remnant of `org.codehaus` in `pom.xml`.

Running `mvn dependency:tree` as suggested by [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13635415/3045181) yields to the same result. If executed on my dev machine, I can find no other jackson library (also no jersey lib which might depend on older jackson)

I tried to delete the `org/codehaus/jackson` directory in `.m2/`, but it just repopulates it automatically.

Possibly related [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26035558/jackson-dependency-version-being-overridden-when-doing-maven-build)

Any ideas anyone?

Comment: Try `maven clean install`

Comment: @randnum-1: Same issue

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nature of the answer is (once again) rather stupid, and not visible in above question. The actual dependency was:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
    <version>${jackson.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

The variable `jackson.version` was defined in this `pom.xml` and in its parent. So, when using the old version it worked because some dependent libs with the overwritten `jackson.version` existed. But with the upgrade which comes with name change, those indirect dependent libs' names do not have the new version. After renaming `jackson.version` to `fasterxml.jackson.version` in the pom, things worked again.

Solution: look more closely at `mvn -X dependency:tree`

Comment: In order that the above build worked one one machine but not on another was because, in the former there was a library with missing dependency information. While in the breaking machine this lib _had_ dep-infos, which resulted the builds into failure.